# How do i use spread operator for multiple vuex modules?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, spread

I looked into another post describing that this should work, but I keep getting the errormessage: '*TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object*'

```
computed: {

    ...mapGetters ("candidates", ["people"] ),

    ...mapGetters ("editPersonDialog" ["tasks"] ),

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo, a comma is missing in `"editPersonDialog" ["tasks"]`. This means that `tasks` key is retrieved from `editPersonDialog` string. Since there's no `tasks` in `String.prototype`, `"editPersonDialog" ["tasks"] === undefined`.

It should be:

```
computed: {

    ...mapGetters ("candidates", ["people"] ),

    ...mapGetters ("editPersonDialog", ["tasks"] ),

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll be more observant in the future.